# Create PDF from UIScrollView (pages after 1st are blank)

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiscrollview

I've been around the block on stack and google trying to get the right way to do this ironed out, any help would be great.

I can render the first page in a PDF but every other page is just blank.

I have a UIScrollView on a view controller in storyboard. I dynamically load content into that scroll view in my view controller's viewDidLoad method. After any item is added I record it's height and then set the content size height of the scroll view accordingly, so the scroll view is fine. It's content width is set to 612

Then I call a function to create a PDF:

```
func createPDF() {

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()

    let scrollHeigt = scrollViewForContent.contentSize.height

    let rawNumberOfPages = scrollHeigt / CGFloat(792)
    let numberOfPages = Int(ceil(rawNumberOfPages))

    var pageNumber = Int()

    let pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792)

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil)
    let pdfContext : CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    do {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil)

        if pageNumber < 1 {

            scrollViewForContent.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext)

        } else if pageNumber >= 1 {

            let offsetForScroll = CGFloat(pageNumber * 792)

            scrollViewForContent.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, offsetForScroll), animated: false)

            CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -offsetForScroll)

            scrollViewForContent.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext)

        }

        pageNumber++

    }
        while pageNumber < numberOfPages

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    let tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()

    let tempDirWithFilename = tempDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test1.pdf")

    pdfData.writeToFile(tempDirWithFilename, atomically: true)

    let aURL : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: tempDirWithFilename)!

    let objectsToShare : NSArray = [aURL]

    let activityVc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    self.presentViewController(activityVc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

How come the data for anything past the first page isn't being rendered? I get the correct number of pages, only the first page has any of the data. Thank you (I'm new and really appreciate you taking the time to look).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should translate the transformation matrix (CTM) of the PDF context the same amount you scroll the `UIScrollView` instance using the function below:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -offsetForScroll);
```

Then your call to `renderInContext` should function properly.

You can see this method in action by looking at the following example that takes the screenshot of the visible area at a particular offset and saves it into an image:

```
scrollViewForContent.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: shiftAmount), animated: false)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollViewForContent.frame.size, true, 0);

CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -scrollViewForContent.contentOffset.y);

scrollViewForContent.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Also, your if conditions are incorrect. Change `else if pageCount > 1` to `else if pageCount >= 1` so that it doesn't skip the page number 1.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I put this directly below setContentOffset (like in your example) - however the 2nd page is still blank.

Comment: I've just tried it in XCode and it works fine. Are you sure that you used the method correctly?

Comment: I added it to the question to show you. I have exactly as you put it.

Comment: Just tried your code, your if conditions are also incorrect. `else if pageNumber > 1` should be `else if pageNumber >= 1`. Currently, it doesn't do anything when `pageNumber = 1`. Other than that, the code works.

Comment: ha, so obsessed with PDF I created another error, thank you, it works!

Comment: Great code, @thefredelement & @Cihan! But when I try to use it, my pdf only works from the point that I was currently scrolled to in the document. Everything _above_ that point is blank. Any idea why that's happening? Do I need to force the scrollview back to the top before implementing the function?

Comment: Answered my own question. If we add `scrollViewForContent.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: false)` before beginning the context, it solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use following code to make PDF file from my UIView. Try it may be it is helpful

```
 // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
        NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, view.bounds, nil);

        //Start your first page
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        //Now render view with subviews to PDF
        [view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

        // Close PDF Render
         UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

For Example

```
-(NSMutableData *)createPDFDatafromUIView:(UIView*)aView
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    Markup *markup;
    for(UIView *view in [aView subviews])
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[Markup class]])
        {
            markup=(Markup*)view;
            break;
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, markup.bounds, nil);

    for(UIView *view in [aView subviews])
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[Markup class]])
        {
            markup=(Markup*)view;



            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
            [markup.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

        }
    }

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return pdfData;
}
```

Comment: I think this might be a better overall way to accomplish my task. I started writing this out, using a xib with two UIViews on it (one for the first page and the 2nd for any page after the first page). Do you have any tips for working out the logic for number of pages? My data is all dynamic.

Comment: Yes I do have logic I have implemented in my code give me some time I will help you

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a really hard time figuring this out. I do a for loop through an array and each array item to the UIView. I keep track of a vertical offset and the current content height to see if it should spawn a new page, but it ends in a huge loop. Also, it doesn't account for strings that may be longer than the content height in the UIView.

Comment: I guess you are render in PDF from UIScrollView. And your UIScrollView must be having so many views. If you iterate through the view in UIScrollView then you will be able to render all views to PDF

Comment: I'm not anymore, i threw that solution away. When I was trying to render the scroll view different things were getting cut off and it was impossible to make it look nice. I just have two UIViews, one is for the first page with some heading information, the other is just a blank page with a page number.

Comment: Then you PDF size dimension is not same as UIView Size dimension. Check the dimension